# How to construct a function with a default argument

Tags: rebol, red

To make a function with default argument, I tried this:

```
f: function [a b] [either unset? :b [a + 1] [a + b]]
f 5
f 3 5
```

then I receive this message `*** Script Error: f is missing its b argument`.
So, what shall I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a trick to implement variable-arity functions that some of the built-ins use, most notably `help`:

```
>> ? help
...
ARGUMENTS:
     'word        [any-type!]
```

Specify your argument as quoted and belonging to `any-type!` typeset. Or, alternatively, list the allowed types and include `unset!` in it.

```
>> foo: func [a 'b [unset! integer!]][a + do pick [1 b] unset? :b]
== func [a 'b [unset! integer!]][a + do pick [1 b] unset? :b]
>> foo 5
== 6
>> foo 3 5
== 8
```

This, however, comes at a certain price:

- Optional arguments must come in succession after the mandatory ones.
- All such function calls within a script now need to be wrapped in parentheses, because otherwise there's no way for the interpreter to guess where your variadic expression ends.
- You lose the benefits of type-checking, since `any-type!` accepts any argument; `'` in front of the argument also enforces [specific](https://github.com/red/red/wiki/%5BDOC%5D-Guru-Meditations#literal-arguments-and-get-arguments) semantics, which makes such variadic functions even more cumbersome.
- Your code becomes unidiomatic: the conventional way to address the need for optional arguments is via refinements. Variadic functions are usually implemented with a single `block!` argument, which might even be dialected.

Such an approach is justified only for user-facing polymorphic functions, intended to be used from command-line prompt (such as `help`) or any other kind of interface that provides clear-cut boundaries for typed expressions (e.g. end of the line, special terminating symbol), and even then the number of optional arguments is kept at minimum.

Comment: Very detail description on this item! Thank you! And also very interesting trick -- `pick [1 b] unset? :b` , I just find that `index` of `pick` can be `logic!`, but where to find how to use it?

Comment: @lyl it's a form of the ternary operator. Expression picks 1st or 2nd value depending on its logical value. Same as in `either`, except that branches are not evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a *refinement*. See: http://helpin.red/Functions.html

For example:

```
>> increase: function [a /add b] [either none? b [a + 1] [a + b]]
== func [a /add b][either none? b [a + 1] [a + b]]
>> increase 3
== 4
>> increase/add 3 5
== 8
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, refinement is a solution. But I think this deviates from the original idea of default argument in function.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible in Red. You can also try to use block as an argument, and block can have as many elements as you want. But that's just a workaround.